# Continuous and bounded - Check my proof please

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

Let $f : [0, ∞) → \mathbb{R}$ be continuous such that $\lim_{x→+∞} f(x) = 0$. Prove that $f$ is bounded on $[0, ∞)$

By our hypothesis and the definition of continuity, given $ c \in [0, \infty), \space \forall \space \epsilon>0, \exists \space \delta >0 \space s.t \space |x-c| \leq \delta \implies |f(x) - f(c)| \leq \epsilon  $

Since $f(c) = 0$, then $|f(x)| \leq \epsilon$ and thus $f$ is bounded on $[0, \infty)$

I am scared because here our $x \to c \implies x \to + \infty$ and so $|x-c| \leq \delta \implies |x - \infty| \leq \delta$ wouldn't make sense?

Comment: How is it that you know that $f(c)=0$?

Comment: First find $M>0$ with $|f(x)|<1$  for $x\ge M$. Then find a bound for $|f|$ on $[0, M]$. One step to go after that ...

Comment: @TimRaczkowski Good point! Why did I assume $c = \infty$ when clearly I stated $c \in [0, \infty)$ =_=

Thanks Davild, I'll give it another attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, there exists some $N\in\mathbb{R}$ such that, for all $x>N$, we have $|f(x)|<1$.

Now consider $[0,N]$. This is a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$, so it is compact. Since $f(x)$ is continuous on this compact set, there exists some $c$ in $[0,N]$ such that $|f(c)|\geq |f(x)|$ for all $x$ in $[0,N]$.

Thus for $x$ in $[0,N]$, $|f(x)|\leq |f(c)|$, and for $x>N$ we have $|f(x)|<1$. Let $M=\max\{|f(c)|,1\}$. Then $f(x)$ is bounded on $[0,\infty)$, as 
$$
-M\leq f(x)\leq M.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying $c= \infty$? I looks strange, even if your idea is correct. I would say this: $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x)=0$ means that for say $\epsilon =1$ there is an $M$ such that  for all $y > M$ is true that $\vert f(x)\vert <  \epsilon =1$. On the other hand, take the closed interval $[0,M+1]$, here the function is bounded, cause it is continuous over a compact.